# What's the best way to find tbody rows in javascript? Regex or ...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What I want to do is to filter a table to only show the tbody that contains a given value against a value entered into a textbox, and to show the filtered rows in a zebra stripe pattern.

The zebra striping is fast, the filtering is generally fast, except on the first filter on a table with a lot of tbodys (say 2000 tbody? ... I haven't measured for the first visible slowdown, and haven't tested for speed by the number, but it's slow in Firefox AND Chrome)

First the JS:

```
//filter results based on query
function filter(selector, query) {
  var regex = new RegExp( query, "i" ); // I did this from memory, may be incorrect, but I know the thing works, the problem is the next part, cos on 5 rows it's fast
  $(selector).each(function() {
    ( regex.test( $(this).text() ) ) < 0) ? $(this).hide().removeClass('visible') : $(this).show().addClass('visible');
  });
}
// then after this I recall the zebra function, which is fast.
```

Then the sample data:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>value to find 1</th>
    <th>value to find 2</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>67890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>empty for now, while testing</td>
    <td>may contain other info later</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>23456</td>
    <td>78901</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>45678</td>
    <td>90123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>

... /ad nauseum, for 2000 rows +

 <tfoot>
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

So for instance, trying to match value `123` would return the first and third rows of this sample data, but I think you already figured that out ...

HELP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you work with this many DOM elements your main performance hit is generally rendering since every time you modify something in the DOM a browser will re-render the page.  This will turn your rendering performance into O(n^2) unless you modify the elements outside of the DOM.  There are a few ways to do this like cloning and DOM arrays.  To use cloning you `clone` the elements you wish to modify, modify the cloned elements and then insert them into the DOM with `replaceWith`.  DOM arrays are just standard JavaScript arrays holding DOM elements.  You can pass an array of DOM elements to jQuery instead of a selector.  Here's the output of my test using copies of your html.  I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.

```
// Using chrome 6.0.472.62
Number of <td> elements: 9524
Optimized Time: 232ms
Normal Time: 21669ms
```

Other modern browsers have different performance characteristics.

```
// Using IE8
Number of <td> elements: 9524
Optimized Time: 1506ms
Normal Time: 4179ms

// Using Firefox 4 Beta
Number of <td> elements: 9524
Optimized Time: 698ms
Normal Time: 2644ms
```

You can see how the O(n^2) rendering really starts to add up.  Here's my test program minus the thousands of copied html elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("Number of <td> elements: " + $("td").length);

  $('input[value=clone]').click(function(){
    function filter(selector, query) {
      var regex = new RegExp( query, "i" );
      var temp = $("table").clone();
      var hide = [];
      var show = [];
      $(selector, temp).each(function() {
        if (regex.test($(this).text())) {
          hide.push(this);
        } else {
          show.push(this);
        }
      });
      $(hide).hide().removeClass('visible');
      $(show).show().addClass('visible');
      $("table").replaceWith(temp);
    }
    var start = (new Date).getTime();
    /* Run a test. */
    filter("td","12345");
    var diff = (new Date).getTime() - start;
    console.log("Optimized Time: " + diff + "ms");
  });

  $('input[value=normal]').click(function(){
    function filter(selector, query) {
      var regex = new RegExp( query, "i" );
      $(selector).each(function() {
        if (regex.test($(this).text())) {
          $(this).hide().removeClass('visible');
        } else {
          $(this).show().addClass('visible');
        }
      });
    }
    var start = (new Date).getTime();
    /* Run a test. */
    filter("td","12345");
    var diff = (new Date).getTime() - start;
    console.log("Normal Time: " + diff + "ms");
  });
});
```

Another option if you don't want to clone is to detach the elements you're working on and then reattach them once your done.  See [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

Comment: Even with swapping you can't obviate the rendering issue. Big tables done as strings via innerHTML still take a while.

Comment: @Robusto I updated my answer showing the performance different on a large table.

Comment: @gradbot: That's fine, and I do like the idea of using `clone` in this context. Nice work. Nevertheless, at some point the hide/show issue is going to come into the equation. removing a few rows causes all the other rows to be re-rendered, which eats up cycles and time.

Comment: So ... testing shows that this regex version is a lot faster. I have not tried Hogan's answer yet tho ...

Comment: I'd be shocked if mine got more performance than this because of the reasons above, but my changes might make this even faster!!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, is this (pun intended) faster?

```
//filter results based on query
function filter(selector, query) {
  var regex = new RegExp( query, "i" ); // I did this from memory, may be incorrect, but I know the thing works, the problem is the next part, cos on 5 rows it's fast
  $(selector).each(function() {
    me = $(this);
    ( regex.test( me.text() ) ) < 0) ? me.hide().removeClass('visible') : me.show().addClass('visible');
  });
}
// then after this I recall the zebra function, which is fast.
```

Should cut down at least one by row constant by 2/3rds.

Also, do you really need to remove and add a class on each row -- if it is hidden you can check for that if you need to know if it is visible or or not.

*use jQuery selectory:*

```
//filter results based on query
// all elements in selector must not have class visible set
function filter(selector, query) {
  var newSel = selectory+":contains('"+query+"')";
  $(newSel).show().addClass('visible');
}

//filter results based on query
// safe version... hides all elements first.
function filter(selector, query) {
  $(selector).hide().removeClass('visible');

  var newSel = selector+":contains('"+query+"')";
  $(newSel).show().addClass('visible');
}
```

Comment: Using this as my inspiration: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-jquery-to-manipulate-and-filter-data/ so that add/remove class was his idea. He uses the filter class to grab the data being zebra'd later. I'm thinking that may be the bottleneck, as it were.

Comment: for sure.  regex might be kinda slow -- of course you don't really have any other options, except to try a jquery selector....

Comment: @drachenstern : note new code -- if no regex you don't need the callback function with jQuery.

Comment: Time constraints being what they are ... I want to test this one, but haven't yet. When I do get a chance to I'll come back and update the status on this

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use a filter function on a set of data, which would be an array of objects. Then you reconstruct the table from the filtered data provider.

There are inherent problems with showing/hiding table rows, not the least of which is the fact that different browsers (I'm looking at you, IE) do the hiding different. Merely setting a row to visibility="hidden" won't do what you want. Setting it to display="none" will, but then you have a problem getting it back. What do you set the display style to in that case? Not "block", certainly. And setting it to table-row behaves differently cross-browser.

Comment: Good commentary. I've considered rebuilding it from scratch each time, wanted to get some input since I've been considering this over the weekend. Got any thoughts on that?

Comment: It should be the case that jQuery handles the cross browser issues with show() and hide() right?

Comment: @drachenstein: This is the only non-kludgey way I can think of to get the alternate row colors (zebra striping). Otherwise you have to iterate through them all each time, which is maybe more hassle than the rebuild. @Hogan: for all I know jQuery would handle that correctly, but it's still a pain and a drain, and the rendering likely wouldn't be much faster than the rebuild.

Comment: I personally would not load 2000 rows into the browser and instead use AJAX to grab the data -- but the question is based on an article which is using jQuery to show and hide rows -- so it is a safe bet it works.  jQuery is like that, it makes crazy cross browser stuff easy (and maybe in this case to easy.)

Comment: @Hogan @Robusto ~ Loading up to 40k rows to be sorted ... figured it was faster to do all my re-rendering client side rather than wait for the potential laggy db connection all for the sake of grepping for something I already have in the browser. (Also, the host page is asp.net, and my co-devs aren't quite as up on AJAX so I need supportable code...)